# Azure pipeline - unzip artefact, copy one directory into Azure blob store YAML file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am getting stuck with Azure pipelines.

I have an existing node SPA project that needs built for each environment (TEST and PRODUCTION). This i can do, but need to have a manual step when pushing to PROD. I am using Azure Dev-op pipeline environments with Approval and Checks to mandate this.

The issue is using a 'deploy job' to take an artefact from a previous step I am unable to find the right directory. This is my YAML file have so far:

```
variables:
# Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

trigger:
- master

# Don't run against PRs
pr: none

stages:
- stage: Development
  displayName: Devlopment stage
  jobs:  
  - job: install
    displayName: Install and test
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
      
    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '12.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'
    
    - script: |
        npm install
      displayName: Install node modules

    - script: |
        npm run build
      displayName: 'Build it'
# Build creates a ./dist folder. The contents will need to be copied to blob store 
      
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: true
        archiveType: 'zip'
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        replaceExistingArchive: true
        verbose: true
  
  - deployment: ToDev
    environment: development
    dependsOn: install
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
            inputs:
              buildType: 'current'
              targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
          - task: ExtractFiles@1
            inputs:
              archiveFilePatterns: '**/*.zip'
              cleanDestinationFolder: true
              destinationFolder: './cpDist/'

# Somehow within a deploy job retrieve the .zip artefact, unzip, copy the ./dist folder into the blob store

          - task: AzureCLI@2
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: MYTEST-Development
              scriptLocation: "inlineScript"
              scriptType: "bash"
              inlineScript: |
                az storage blob upload-batch -d \$web --account-name davey -s dist --connection-string 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=davey;AccountKey=xxxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy.zzzzzzzzzz;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'
            displayName: "Copy build files to Development blob storage davey"

          - script: |
              pwd
              ls
              cd cpDist/
              pwd
              ls -al
            displayName: 'list'
          
          - bash: echo "Done"
```

Comment: After the archive files task it looks to me you are missing a PublishPipelineArtifacts task - hence your deployment will never find any files. Also you can remove the download step at the beginning of the Deployment job as a deployment job already does an implicit download of any available artifacts.

Comment: @alv, yep you are correct.I reread the docs again last night and solved my issue doing exactly that. Thanks for the confirmation. I'll write up and put the solution here with notes over the next few days incase anyone else has the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are confused with the folder path, you could add few debug steps to check the location of know system variables to understand what was going on using a powershell script as below:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Degug parameters'
  inputs:
    targetType: Inline
    script: |
      Write-Host "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
      Write-Host "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
      Write-Host "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)"
      Write-Host "$(Pipeline.Workspace)"
      Write-Host "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)"
```

You should simply [publish the build generated artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#publishing-artifacts) to **drop** folder.

Kindly check this official doc -- [Artifact selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml-task#artifact-selection) , in there is explaining that you can define the path which to download the artifacts to with the following task:

```
steps:
- download: none
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  displayName: 'Download Build Artifacts'
  inputs:
    patterns: '**/*.zip'
    path: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Please be aware that the download happens automatically to $(Pipeline.Workspace), so if you don’t want you deployment to download the files twice, you need to specify the “download: none” in your steps.